# Speech to text converstions on live streaming audio

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I want to throw the speech to text conversions on my console when the user has stopped speaking. For it, I installed speech_recognition module and python2.

When I run on command line `python -m speech_recognition` it is able to detect the end of the user speech, convert it and print it on my console and returning back to listen the audio from mic until I stop running the program. In this case, I am not sure which converter it is using, but the output is accurate enough

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
A moment of silence, please...
Set minimum energy threshold to 1806.92166802
Say something!
Got it! Now to recognize it...
I am testing this speech converters. I am done!
Say something!
Got it! Now to recognize it...
The second test tw going on.
```

Now I am trying to reproduce by doing speech recognition through controlled way, using the code snippets examples given and I have chosen Microsoft bing for conversions.

```
def convert_speech_to_text(audio):
    message = sr.Recognizer().recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY)
    return(message)

while True:
# try: 
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        sr.Recognizer().adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print(1,'say')
        audio = sr.Recognizer().listen(source)

    print("Converting")
    message = convert_speech_to_text(audio)
    print(message)
# except: 
   # print("error")
```

It is stuck after printing (1,'say'), it doesn't end listening to the mic, no conversions are made and not coming back to listening.

Is there any way I can reproduce what the command `python -m speech_recognition` does as .py file?

Comment: Just from looking at an example https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/speech-recognition/ You may want to only create one recognizer `r = sr.Recognizer()` then use `r` instead of `sr.Recognizer()` multiple times. Don't know if that is the problem or not.

Comment: In the link you gave,from command line execution works fine, but the code example does not work. Now I can understand that it is using Google demo key. In my program, I have used Microsoft bing instead of google.